# How to make pundit policies more DRY?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pundit

In one of my project I started to using pundit gem and I have a very simply policy that looks like this:

```
class CompanyPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  def index?
    true if user.is_a? Administrator
  end

  def new?
    true if user.is_a? Administrator
  end

  def create?
    new?
  end

  def edit?
    true if user.is_a? Administrator
  end

  def update?
    edit?
  end
end
```

And the question is how can I avoid repeating this:

```
true if user.is_a? Administrator
```

Comment: try using `before_filter` and call it on all the above methods

Comment: This is pundit policy class not controller and I can't use before_filter...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do trick which looks like this:

```
class ApplicationPolicy

  private

  def self.permit_owner_to(*actions)
    actions.each do |action|
      define_method("#{action}?") do
        owner?
      end
    end
  end

  def owner?
    # owner logic
  end

end
```

And used it in other policies

```
class ItemPolicy < ApplicationPolicy

  permit_owner_to :show, :update, :destroy, :confirm

end
```

Comment: what about the case when you have like admin, staff, manager and so on? would you define a permit method for everyone in application controller?

Answer (score 3):

I don't actually think you need to remove this. By repeating this you are explicitly saying that this user must be an administrator to access this method.  If you did want to though, you could just create a private method.

```
class CompanyPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  def index?
    admin?
  end

  def new?
    admin?
  end

  def create?
    new?
  end

  def edit?
    admin?
  end

  def update?
    edit?
  end

  private 
     def admin?
        user.is_a? Administrator
     end
end
```

Guess this is a matter of personal preference.

Comment: By keeping this test spread throughout the code base you risk a big problem if/when you decide to implement the test in a different way.  For example, what if you chose to have an administrator _role_ rather than administrator _class_?  Lots of refactoring.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `alias_method`.

```
class CompanyPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  def index?
    user.is_a? Administrator
  end

  alias_method :create?, :index?
  alias_method :update?, :index?
end
```

You have a base class `ApplicationPolicy` which probably already contains:

```
def new?
  create?
end

def edit?
  update?
end
```

so you don't need to repeat these methods in your subclass.

`.is_a?` returns `true` or `false` so no need to explicitly return `true if true`.

That's a lot more succinct eh? :)

Answer (score 0):

I combined answers from above and came up with the following:

```rb
class ApplicationPolicy
  attr_reader :user

  def initialize(user)
    @user = user
  end

  def self.permit(roles, options)
    return if options[:to].none?

    options[:to].each do |action|
      define_method("#{action}?") do
        return @user.roles? Array.wrap(roles) if options[:when].blank?

        send(options[:when]) and @user.roles? Array.wrap(roles)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

which allows one to use it like this:

```rb
class CommentPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  attr_reader :user, :record

  def initialize(user, record)
    @record = record
    super(user)
  end

  permit %i[admin member], to: %i[show edit destroy update], when: :created_by_user

  def created_by_user
    @record.user == @user
  end
end
```

and

```rb
permit :admin, to: %i[index update edit]
```

works as well

my roles method from `user` model looks like:

```rb
def roles?(user_roles)
    user_roles.each do |role|
      return true if role?(role)
    end
    false
  end

  def role?(role)
    roles.any? { |r| r.name.underscore.to_sym == role }
  end
```